# MSBuild strange build issues

Tags: c#, build, reportviewer

I'm trying to set up a build machine and have managed to get everything up and running. This is the last bit I'm stuck on. I tried to un/reinstall ReportViewer 10, and also tried to install versions 8 and 9 to see if it would resolve the problem but with no success. Anyway here's the error:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll: error CS1684:
>   Warning as Error: Reference to type  Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingResult' claims it is defined in 'c:\
>   Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.
>   Common.dll', but it could not be found

And similarly,

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll: error CS1684: Warning as Error: Reference to type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.Warning' claims it is defined in 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll', but it could not be found

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: When does this error occur? When installing ReportViewer?

Comment: sorry, I should have been clearer: this happens when I try to build a solution that references it. I cannot modify that solution though.

Comment: Do the assemblies exist at the location that it is referencing? `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`

Comment: Yes, everything is there

Comment: Do you have Reflector? If so, can you open it up with Reflector and find the class there?

Comment: before I try that there's one thing I noticed: the winforms.dll is in the vs 9.0 program folder, but the reference is to a dll in the vs 10.0 folder, I think that this might be the problem..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll` there is a class definition which uses `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingResult` as base class;

```
public class foo : Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RenderingResult
{
}
```

You use this `foo` class somewhere in your code. The class `RenderingResult` is defined in `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`. This class requires the same version of `RenderingResult` to be referenced. Because you use the 9.0 version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll and the 10.0 version of Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll they do not match. The `RenderingResult` is different in the 10.0 version, so the `foo` class definition is incomplete.

To resolve this, you need to make sure you use the matching assemblies, for example you might need to manually adjust the `HintPath` in the .csproj file to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In case anyone ever has this problem your answer is correct. I still remember the problem and it was solved by changing the hint path to the correct version. Without changing the hint path, the wrong DLL got referenced.